# Syntax error Unexpected Quantifier in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

trying to build regex in javascript but getting syntax error and unexpected quantifier. Anyone knows how to replace ?

```
expr1 =/"^(("[^"]*"@)|(([-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])@))" +"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$"/;
```

Comment: Your regex seems to have unmatched parentheses and invalid groups ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?  Hard to help you build a new one when all we have to go on is a version that doesn't work.   ;)

Comment: This regex is intended to be used for email verification and same regex works fine for asp.net/c# code when i put it on aspx page or front end it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

`(?` could not work (pos 143). `?` is at the beginning of a group.

In c#, there is a alternation group in the form of `(?(..)..|..)`. There is nothing similar in JavaScript.